# python monkey patching an object's method within a function via a decorator

Tags: python, mocking, monkeypatching

I'm trying to learn some advanced decorator usage. Specifically, I'm trying to  to monkey patch a class's method via a decorator within a function.

This is a basic example to illustrate what I'm trying to do. I have a function `something` that does some stuff; and within that function there's an instance of a class. That instance I would like to monkey patch.

```
from functools import update_wrapper

class Foobar:
    def get_something(self):
        return "apple"

class FakeFoobar:
    def get_something(self):
        return "orange"

class my_decorator:
    def __init__(self, original_function):
        self._original_function = original_function
        update_wrapper(self, original_function)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # some magic here?
        return self._original_function(*args, **kwargs)

@my_decorator
def something():
    f = Foobar()
    return f.get_something()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(something())
```

I'm trying either trying to do a 1 to 1 replacement with `Foobar` to `FakeFoobar` or, monkey patch `Foobar`'s `get_something` method to `FakeFoobar`'s `get_something` method.

When I run the code above, I get the following:

```
>>> something()
'apple'
>>>
```

I would like to find some way augment the `Foobar`'s `get_something` method so that we get the following output:

```
>>> something()
'orange'
>>>
```

There's a `mock` module within the `unittests` library, however, it's not clear to be how I could leverage that for my use case. I'm fairly married to the idea of not passing an argument into the decorator or an extra argument into the `something` function as many of the examples of the [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#patch-decorators) library show.

I also notice that the [moto library](https://github.com/spulec/moto) is accomplishing something similar to what I'm trying to do. I tried digging into the source code, but it seems fairly complex for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about updating the global variables dict of the function?

```
from functools import update_wrapper

class Foobar:
    def get_something(self):
        return "apple"

class FakeFoobar:
    def get_something(self):
        return "orange"

class my_decorator:
    def __init__(self, original_function):
        self._original_function = original_function
        update_wrapper(self, original_function)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = self._original_function
        restore_val = f.func_globals['Foobar']
        f.func_globals['Foobar'] = f.func_globals['FakeFoobar']
        # ^^^^^ This is your magic-line.
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            raise
        finally:
            f.func_globals['Foobar'] = restore_val

@my_decorator
def something():
    f = Foobar()
    return f.get_something()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(something())   #Prints orange
    print(Foobar().get_something()) #Prints apple
```

Comment: This is pretty close. The problem is that it updates the globals for the entire module so if I re-instantiate `Foobar` outside of the `something` function I get back `FakeFoobar` which is not desirable.

Comment: @user5038859: You can always restore the variable as in the answer that I just updated.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you. Before I mark this as the answer, please accept my edits for python3 support.